# Attaching an Image to Work item in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: api, azure-devops, attachment

I'm sending an attachment through the Visual Studio Team Services API and it all look like its fine, until I look at the attachment on the work item.

The attachment should be a picture, but it a little black box with a white cross.

Has anyone had this issue and does anyone know what I've done wrong?

I get the image and convert it to a 64 Base string

```
   FileInfo info = new FileInfo(attachment.Path);
   byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(info.FullName);
   String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Then I send it to the API.  This returns a message saying its been successful.

```
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {


                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                             new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                             Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(getConnectionDetails())));


                using (System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(SetURL(url),
                    new StringContent(binaryString,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")).Result)
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
```

I think its something small, that I'm missing!

This is the link to the document, I have used.

[API document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
...
string uri = "https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=test.jpg&api-version=1.0";
string filepath = "C:\\images\\test.jpg";
FileStream files = new FileStream(filepath,FileMode.Open);
StreamContent streamcontent = new StreamContent(files);
...
HttpResponseMessage response = hc.PostAsync(uri, streamcontent).Result;
...
```